# Pig error in hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I am a beginner in Hadoop. My pig code in hortonworks sandbox is:

```
raw=load 'SchoolDataSet.csv' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.hcatloader();

es=foreach raw generate times as timestamp,ip,country,status;

store es into 'SchoolDataSet.csv'using org.dataset.hadoop.pig.esstorage();

stock_a=load 'SchoolDataSet.csv' using pigstore(',')

AS (name:chararray,TypeofSchool:chararray,

SexStudents:boolean, Branchofstudy:chararray,

Evidence:chararray, FieldofStudy:chararray,

Side:chararray,Status:chararray, Cityoffice:chararray,

LessonName:chararray,PersonalCode:int,

SchoolCode:int, LessonCode:int,NumberOfStudents:int,

OfreNewal:int,ReasonableNumber:int,

Meanscores:float,Acceptancerate:float,Experience:int);

describe stock_a;

B = LIMIT STOCK_A 100;

DESCRIBE B;

dump b;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE symbol, date, close;

DESCRIBE C;

STORE C INTO 'output/C';
```

And error is this in sandbox:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/hive/lib/slf4j-api-*.jar: No such file or directory

2015-05-15 12:37:13,349 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig    version 0.12.1.2.1.1.0-385

(rexported) compiled Apr 16 2014, 15:59:00

2015-05-15 12:37:13,350 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to:

/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/appcache/application_1431515718576_0020/container_143151

5718576_0020_01_000002/pig_1431718633347.log

2015-05-15 12:37:14,510 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file

/home/yarn/.pigbootup not found

2015-05-15 12:37:14,869 [main] INFO   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -

mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtrac
1 of 2
Displaying SandBoxCode.docx.
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: If you are using Hcat then you should provide table name insteed of file or you should provide full path of file.

Answer (score 0):

You could be getting this error because have not updated your .bashrc variables. Go vi ~/.bashrc then insert

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.12.0 
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
```

Then try executing pig in mapreduce version:

pig -x mapreduce

Now you can execute your pig script via "grunt>". If you want to run a shell script try this:https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell